# How to visit link by just entering single word?

Tags: php, google-chrome, http, url, localhost

I have a link: https://stckoverflow.com/questions/64086115/how-to-visit-link-by-just-entering-single-word

How can I visit this link directly by entering just `myquestion/` in chrome?

Another example,

I have a link: https://mywebsite.com/something/something/somethingmore?id=0&uid=1&text=sometext&somethingothers

How can I visit this link directly by entering just `mywebsite/` in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possibilities and one of the most used is "other search engines"

you practically tell chrome that the link is a search engine

add the URL in your bar and right click on it edit search engines," then scroll down to the bottom of the preferences page that pops up. Enter a name for the URL you're adding in the first empty slot, then give it a short alias. Then just paste the URL in the last field and hit the Tab key.